# ST_BOUNDARY in Oracle Spatial

Tags: oracle-spatial

ST_Boundary is in the Oracle Spatial docs here:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/spatl/sql-multimedia-type-support.html#GUID-22FE0E11-C9F0-4E1A-B512-D494E588FFAA

But only as an example:

```
SELECT c.shape.ST_BOUNDARY() 
  FROM cola_markets c WHERE c.name = 'cola_b';
```

It runs but always returns NULL, is this an oversight or something else? It doesn't throw a syntax issue so something is going on?

```
SELECT c.shape FROM cola_markets c
```

Returns a regular ST_GEOMETRY with no issue.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to report what happens when you query just `c.shape`

Comment: Done. It returns a regular geometry. The other methods work fine.